# I want to plot horizontal single stacked graphs in grey scale inside each cell of a table. Is there a way of doing it?

Tags: tables, graphs

Each bar has three parts. I want to have the value to annotated inside the parts too.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you use `pgfplots` pacakge, combine options `ybar stacked/xbar stacked` with
`nodes near coords`, see examples in [manual of `pgfplots` v1.17](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf?revision=54041&view=co&pathrev=54041), sec. 4.5.9 _Stacked Plots_, subsec _Stacked Bar Plots and Nodes Near Coords_.

Comment: Thank you so much!